# Unknown socket family 0 in grpc_sockaddr_get_port Error

Tags: tensorflow, grpc

While running tests in TensorFlow v1.4.0 many failures seen due to error:

```
..E1113 09:39:05.891581609   54654 ev_epoll1_linux.c:1051]     grpc epoll fd: 3
E1113 09:39:05.892042359   54654 sockaddr_utils.c:239]       Unknown socket family 0 in grpc_sockaddr_get_port
E1113 09:39:05.892056484   54654 tcp_server_utils_posix_common.c:90] assertion failed: port > 0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Also few fail with error:

```
self.server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))   
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'server'
```

Installed grpc via pip. Anyone faced similar error?

Comment: Did you `pip install grpc` or did you `pip install grpcio`?

Comment: Tried pip install grpc. But that doesn't matter I guess. TensorFlow downloads gRPC source and uses that. Could see that earlier version of gRPC commit(d7ff4ff) worked fine, however in latest TensorFlow, it has been updated to 781fd6f6 which is having above issue while starting server.

Comment: I suspect that it does matter - if you do a `pip freeze` and see both `grpc` and `grpcio` listed, that's likely a problem, because both are probably trying to provide code elements under the `grpc` package name within the interpreter.

Comment: `pip freeze` gives only : grpc==0.3.post19

Comment: It has stopped working since `v1.1.0-pre1` till latest version. The last working tag was `objective-c-v1.0.2`.